# What is the set variable corresponding to a random variable?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

I stumbled upon an interesting looking work by R. Yeung that shows an interesting relation between information and measure theory called [A New Outlook on Shannon’s Information Measures](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/%7Echaos/courses/poci/Readings/Yeung.IEEETransInfo1991.pdf). In this work the author frequently uses the notion of a "set variable $\tilde{X}$ corresponding to a random variable $X$". I have never heard of such a notion.

Unfortunately, for the author it seems to be common knowledge as he does not explain it. Even more frustrating, looking for such a notion only lead me to other articles by the same author and in none of them I found an explanation.

Does someone know what is meant by "a set variable corresponding to a random variable" or, even better, can point me to a reference where such a notion is explained?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Given that the author takes the union of set variables, I suspect they mean by a "set variable" some confusing superposition of the name for the set of values, and a symbol that is regarded as ranging somehow across that set of values.

Comment: Thank you @LSpice for your reply! From what the author claims in his work, e.g. $I(X;Y) = \mu(X \cap Y)$, I can deduce that he means something deeper than $\tilde{X}=X(\Omega)$ , as there are clearly $X$ and $Y$ with positive mutual information but $X(\Omega) \cap Y(\Omega) = \varnothing$.

Comment: Turns out there is a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory_and_measure_theory) on this. Although I can't say the article explains it in sufficient detail for me, I have now the impression as if the "set variable" is nothing but an abstract representation - you can pick whatever you like as long as you satisfy some basic conditions.